# Are Black Holes 4 dimensional?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon

I was thinking about if Black Holes are 4th dimensional.

I know that spacetime inside a black hole scrambles (not sure if this is the correct term) very fast to produce more space, like a bag that is always getting deeper by the second, it's also why you cannot escape it.

Furthermore, as the Einstein-Rosen bridge idea states that black holes extend into the fourth dimension, at least to my understanding, and it's why you can entangle them via the 4th dimension, a wormhole.

To segway to my conclusion, would it be rational to think that a black hole is a 4th-dimensional sphere because of the Einstein-Rosen bridge theory, but without the entanglement? Just one black hole.

I apologize if this is obvious or a "*stupid*" question to ask. PS: I am not a math guy, so please try to avoid a mostly mathematical answer.

Comment: "*spacetime inside a black hole scrambles (not sure if this is the correct term) very fast to produce more space, like a bag that is always getting deeper by the second*" - Something like this happens outside the horizon for an observer slowly approaching the horizon (not falling), but inside a Schwarzschild black hole space rapidly shrinks. "*the Einstein-Rosen bridge idea states that black holes extend into the fourth dimension,*" - Also incorrect. There is no fourth spatial dimension in the bridge. The bridge takes you to a hypothetical different universe that also has 3 spatial dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @safesphere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, black holes are four-dimensional. Spacetime is four-dimensional (three dimensions of space and one dimension of time), and black holes are just a particular type of curved spacetime.

No, black holes are not four-dimensional spheres. For example, far from a black hole, spacetime is effectively flat rather than curved.

Comment: Just a side note, because I'm curious, wouldn't that prove that higher dimensional space exists? And why do Physicists today say there are no higher dimensions or proof of such?

Comment: They are talking about possible additional *spatial* dimensions.

Comment: @Compilerv2 When you say 4th dimensional did you mean 4th spatial dimension or did you mean time as the 4th dimension?

Comment: I meant 4th as spatial.

Comment: Black holes do not have a fourth spatial dimension.

Comment: But they are in time?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Spacetime has four dimensions: 3 of space, 1 of time. Black holes are a particular kind of curved spacetime. What about those statements are unclear?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Compilerv2 We don't know what's inside of a blackhole so we cannot answer that question (except perhaps in speculative terms). We also do not know if there are additional spatial dimensions hitherto not experienced by us. There are serious scientists who believe there are and those that believe there are not.

Comment: @ApoorvKhurasia I hope you would agree that black holes do not *require* additional spatial dimensions, since they exist just fine in 3+1D GR.

Comment: @G.Smith Of course. No disagreement there. I was just trying to clarify his second question on the first comment "why do physicists today say there are no higher dimensions...."

Answer (score -4):

I would say that black holes are fourth dimensional, but the shape may or may not be, as a sherical object can only be in the fourth dimension if they are in circular or cylindrical form and not spherical. For example, the orbitals of an atom in which the electrons flow could extend in various ways so they can exist in both 3D and 4D, and this implies the fourth and third spatial dimensions.